# Переход по элементам списка .next() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
if (e.which == 40) 
{
   $(".list-ul").next(".list-li").focus();
   element.val($(".list-li").val());
}
```

Подразумевается переход по списку

```
<ul class = "list-ul">
  <li class = "list-li"></li>
   ....
  <li class = "list-li"></li>
</ul>
```

но что то не работает. Как правильно?

Comment: не работает, потому что вызываете [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) у списка и желаете итерировать потомков, а он соседний нод возвращает. Т.е. соседний с `ul`, а не дочерний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас путаница, потому-что вам и `ul` надо задействовать, и `li` сфокусированный, а все должно быть четко:

```js
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    //проверяем выбрано ли что-либо
    if($(".list-li:focus").length!==0){
        //если выбрано, выбираем следующий элемент
        $(".list-li:focus").next(".list-li").focus();
    }else{
        //если не выбрано, выбираем первый элемент 
        $(".list-ul .list-li").eq(0).focus();
    }
    $('#element').val($(".list-li:focus").text())
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-ul">
  <li class="list-li" tabindex="1">1</li>
  <li class="list-li" tabindex="2">2</li>
  <li class="list-li" tabindex="3">3</li>
</ul>
<input id=element>
```